# Path of given sum in Binary Tree - in Recursion | Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, backtracking

i wrote a code that needs to check and print on binary tree if there is a path from root forward that if we sum the objects in every step we will get the given sum.

for example:

```
     1
    /  \
  4     1
 / \   / \
8   2 6   8
   / \   / \
 10   5 2   8
```

and let's say that we are given the number 5.
the program needs to return in string "1, 4" - because it gives togther the sum 5.

if we are given the number 8, the program will return in string "1, 1, 6" - because togther it gives the sum 8.

that is the program that i wrote:

```
    public String sum(int x)    {
    return sum(x, root, 0, "");
}

private String sum(int x, Node tree, int num, String s) {

    if(tree == null)
        return "";

    if(num == x) {
        s=s+tree.getNumber() + ", ";
        return s;
    }

    if (num != x)

        s=s+tree.getNumber() + ", ";
        sum(x, tree.getLeftSon(), num, s);
        sum(x, tree.getRightSon(), num, s);

return s;
```

when I run the code it looks like its all good - but when it get into the end of the condition in "if(num == x)" - it just doesnt return the value!

i run the debugger, and got al the right values that i wanted. if the program would return the value of s and stop itself - my program will work as i like. but it just continue to the next "if" and i dont know what to do...

help will be much appricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code ignores the return values of these calls:

```
    sum(x, tree.getLeftSon(), num, s);
    sum(x, tree.getRightSon(), num, s);
```

that's probably why you get the wrong result.
 The line

```
 s=s+tree.getNumber() + ", ";
```

will create a new variable and assign it to "s" but will not change the original variable "s" which you passed in. In Java you can't pass a reference, therefore you have to use the return value.